# Forcing static files to never cache

Tags: django, apache

I'm serving a Django app on top of Apache, and after my recent deployments, I noticed that a lot of users were being served the new version of the main HTML file, but they were still picking up the older JS files from their Cache.

I tried stuff like `patch_cache_control(response, no_cache=True, no_store=True, must_revalidate=True)`, but this doesn't seem to work for static files.

Is there a way to always force every static to be re-fetched from the server when a page is accessed?

Comment: Google: `E-Tag`, `Last-Modified-Since`. Apache should be able to add these headers when serving static files. Your browser will determine, based on these headers, if it should pull the static file from it's cache or not. Plus: to increase performance, serve static  files directly and not through Django. This should be handled by your webserver only.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lot of stuff with your headers.

Or you could use something like `{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}?v={{ settings.CURRENT_VERSION }}`, this way the browser would think that you are using a completely new file, because the name of the file would be something like `jquery.js?v=1`. I would not really recommend doing this, but it is a really quick hack.